# Griffiths Quantum mechanics example 4.3

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

The example goes as follows:

> Imagine a particle of spin $1/2$ at rest in a uniform magnetic field which points in the z-direction: $$\textbf{B} = B_0 \hat{k}$$ The Hamiltonian is $$ H = -\gamma B_0S_z = \frac{\gamma  
>  B_0 \hbar}{2} 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0\\ 
> 0 & -1\\
> \end{pmatrix} $$ The eigenstates of $H$ are the same as $S_z$. Since the Hamiltonian is time independent , the general solution to the time-dependent Schrodinger equation, $$i\hbar \frac{\partial \chi}{\partial t} = H \chi$$ can be expressed in terms of stationary states: $$\chi(t) = \begin{pmatrix}ae^{\frac{i \gamma B_0 t}{2}} \\ be^{\frac{-i \gamma B_0 t}{2}} \end{pmatrix} $$ The constants $a,b$ are determined by $$\chi(0) = \begin{pmatrix} a\\ b \end{pmatrix} $$

Its easy to understand what the eigenstates are, and I really understand that part. But Griffiths goes on to say that we can write $ a=  \cos(\alpha /2)$ and $b = \sin(\alpha/2)$. I know that we don't know exactly where the spinor is pointing, so we have this case, but why this in specific? How did he use this without proving that this is the case, and how do we use those initial conditions to do so? Would $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=b$ not hold as well? I'm just curious as to how we can use those initial conditions to figure this out?

Comment: It might look like $a$ and $b$ could be anything depending on the initial conditions, however they are related by the normalization condition $\chi^\dagger(t)\chi(t) = 1$. This leads to $a^2+b^2=1$. Then, you can say: I am going to call $a=\cos\alpha/2$. Then $b^2=1-a^2=\cos \alpha/2$.

Comment: sure but with the same token if $a^2+b^2 =1$ then $a=b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ also holds as a solution to that?

Comment: @Ivan The normalization condition leads to $|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}=1$, and the difference matters.  The phase of $a/b$ determines the azimuthal orientation of $\langle\vec{S}\rangle$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @Joey $a=b=1/\sqrt{2}$ is just a special case of $a=\cos\alpha/2$ and $b=\sin\alpha/2$ with $\alpha=\pi/2$.

Comment: Right and I see that it is a special case, but why can we just use $a= cos(\alpha/2), b = \sin(\alpha/2)$? Why these functions in particular?

Comment: @Joey You start off with $2$ real numbers for $a$ (aka $1$ complex number) and $2$ for $b$. There is one constraint, $|a|^2 + |b|^2=1$, and the overall phase of the wavefunction does not matter. So we can describe $a$ and $b$ using two real numbers. We can express $a$ and $b$ as $a=\cos\alpha/2$ and $b=e^{i\delta}\sin\alpha/2$, with the two real numbers $\alpha, \delta$. This is just a general parameterization of the solution to the normalization condition and choosing the overall phase of the wavefunction so $a$ is real. I don't know why Griffifths assumes $\delta=0$.